# React native webview autolink results in "package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist" error. Do you know any fix to this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to use react native webview and autolink it to our react native codebase. For this I have done the following steps and get the error that is posted at the end of this post. Could you please help me to fix this error?

I added

```
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
```

to the settings.gradle file and

```
implementation project(':react-native-webview')
```

to the build.gradle file.

When I run gradle clean build in android folder or run react-native run android in root folder, it gives the following error:

````
 Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:63: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingErrorEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:64: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopHttpErrorEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:65: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingFinishEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:66: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingProgressEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:67: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingStartEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:68: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopMessageEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:69: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent;
                                              ^
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:553: error: cannot find symbol
    export.put(TopLoadingProgressEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onLoadingProgress"));
               ^
  symbol:   variable TopLoadingProgressEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewManager
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:554: error: cannot find symbol
    export.put(TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onShouldStartLoadWithRequest"));
               ^
  symbol:   variable TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewManager
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:556: error: cannot find symbol
    export.put(TopHttpErrorEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onHttpError"));
               ^
  symbol:   variable TopHttpErrorEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewManager
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:947: error: cannot find symbol
        new TopLoadingProgressEvent(
            ^
  symbol:   class TopLoadingProgressEvent
  location: class RNCWebChromeClient
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:752: error: cannot find symbol
        new TopLoadingStartEvent(
            ^
  symbol:   class TopLoadingStartEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewClient
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:762: error: cannot find symbol
        new TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent(
            ^
  symbol:   class TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewClient
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:810: error: cannot find symbol
        new TopLoadingErrorEvent(webView.getId(), eventData));
            ^
  symbol:   class TopLoadingErrorEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewClient
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:828: error: cannot find symbol
          new TopHttpErrorEvent(webView.getId(), eventData));
              ^
  symbol:   class TopHttpErrorEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewClient
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:835: error: cannot find symbol
        new TopLoadingFinishEvent(
            ^
  symbol:   class TopLoadingFinishEvent
  location: class RNCWebViewClient
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:1156: error: cannot find symbol
              dispatchEvent(webView, new TopMessageEvent(webView.getId(), data));
                                         ^
  symbol: class TopMessageEvent
\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:1167: error: cannot find symbol
          dispatchEvent(this, new TopMessageEvent(this.getId(), eventData));
                                  ^
  symbol:   class TopMessageEvent
  location: class RNCWebView
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: \node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
18 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I remember this error.. check if your ./android/gradle.properties file has this added / changed it may resolve the issue:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that the react-native-webview package under node modules was not containing the events package and that was the cause of this problem. I have no idea why it was not containing events package but deleting node modules and running npm clean-install again made it loaded with the events package and thus this problem is resolved.